# Vscode keep running tests or run on save

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, testing, protractor

I am using VS Code in order to fix a lot of UI tests.
They are written in `TypeScript` with `protractor` and `jasmine`.
I am running the tests using a `launch.json` file for these tests.

What I want is to run the tests all the time, so while i am fixing my tests, I'll always get an indication if the tests were correctly fixed, and I won't need to explicitly run it and wait for the results.
Another good enough option for me would be to run it on a save.

Comment: why don't you use the **Test View**, launch is for debugging